# When to use Oauth and API key authentication types

Tags: api, oauth, api-key

I get it that Oauth is used to grant permission to a third party application to access a user's data (like photos on his facebook account) without revelaing his facebook credentials to the third party application. For example, when you try to use an online photo editing tool and you want to load a photo from facebook, facebook will pop up a message asking whether you really want to allow the application to access your data. So at that point facebook just returns a temporary access token and the app can use it to access your facebook photos. (as i understand the scope for this access token is such that it only has permission to access the particular user's photos only) Yes, this sort of a setup is required because you can't trust a third party application that much as to give away your credentials.

Assume somehow instead of oauth, facebook used api key authentication. This would mean that all third party applications that have subscribed for facebook API already have a key which they can use to access facebook's data sources.So that the app can directly take you to your facebook photos and facebook will not notify you that an outsider is trying to access your private data. This approach is not suitable for an api that exposes user sensitive data but for apis that expose not so user specific (like google maps) data, the api key approach should be enough, right ?

So my question is, what are the criterion to decide which authentication type should be used ? And appreciate feedback if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 of the standard 4 Oauth2 flows which cater for the scenarios you mention.

- Authorisation Code
- Client Credentials.

Using your Facebook example above you could think of like this:

Use Authorisation Code flow for your "Oauth" scenario, where your app needs delegated authorisation to access a user's Facebook photos. This means the user must login and grant access to your app *and* your app must have an API key (client ID) issued by Facebook.

Use the client credentials flow for your "API Key" scenario. This would be when your app needs access to, for example, public Facebook pages / info and thus does not require specific user consent and can just use its API Key (Client Id & Client Secret)